# Boilerplate needed for spfx web parts that has all layout options (grid, carousel, compact, etc)

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

To all the SharePoint developers out there, do you know of a GitHub repo of a boilerplate spfx web part that has all the layout options a normal sharepoint widget/web part would have? (Grid, Filmstrip, List, Carousel & Compact layouts?)

[image]

It seems strange Microsoft doesen't offer us one :/

Comment: Try this out https://github.com/hugoabernier/WebPartDesignSeries/tree/master/WebPartLayouts